# Stacked image and plot in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am new to Python and trying to create figures similar to ones I made using IDL.
I am trying to make a plot like the one below (do not worry about the data it represents):

[image]

As you can see, this figure is an image displayed adjacent to a line plot.
As I've tried to recreate this in Python I have ran into some issues, please see my code to plot below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot
import numpy as numpy
import pandas as pandas

fig, ax = pyplot.subplots(2, 1, sharex = True, gridspec_kw={'hspace': 0})
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)
ax[0].imshow(rot_selected_logfile1[::-1], cmap='rainbow')
ax[1].pyplot(testarr, testarr)
ax[0].axis('off')

pyplot.show()
```

This is what it outputs:

[image]

There are some thing's that I need to happen to this that I cannot figure out on my own. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
1. I need the image to be completely adjacent to the line plot, but for some reason I just can't figure out to do this (If you see my code, I have attempted, but can't get it to work).
2. I need to get rid of the current axes for the image, and then create another set of axes **over** the image.
3. I want to be able to stretch the image so that each pixel isn't completely square and more like the example figure I attached.

Any help on anything would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Another piece of advice that doesn't appear in your question: It seems like you want to use a logarithmic scale, so that you are plotting something like `plt.imshow(numpy.log(data))`. However zero coefficients take the value `-inf` when the logarithm is applied and appear as white pixel. To avoid this, import `from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm` and use it with `plt.imshow(data, norm=LogNorm())`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the problem of the horizontal space not working and the fixed aspect ratio of the image plot are caused by `imshow` defaulting to an aspect ratio similar to the image dimensions. `aspect='auto'` changes this to the default behavior for regular graphs.

To get x-ticks below the image, and considering that the image and the line plot use shared x-axes, a secondary x-axis can be drawn at the top of the lower graph. Setting its ticks and its ticklabels inside should get the desired result.

Ticks at all sides can be set via `tick_params`.

To set the correct x and y axes for the image, the `extent=` parameter of `imshow` can be used.

The code below tries to recreate a plot similar to the one in the question. As `imshow` doesn't seem to work nice with a lognorm, the lognorm is applied directly to the image.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import ticker, colors
import numpy as np

N = 200
x0, x1 = 18, 22
y0, y1 = 0, 100
values = np.abs(np.random.uniform(-0.5, 0.55, N).cumsum())
values[N // 2:] += 10
img = np.zeros((30, N))
img[0, :] = 3 ** values
for i in range(1, img.shape[0]):
    img[i, :] = img[i-1, :] * 0.01

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex=True, gridspec_kw={'hspace': 0})
norm=colors.LogNorm(vmin=1, vmax=1e6)
plot0 = ax[0].imshow(norm(img), cmap='rainbow',
                      aspect='auto', extent=[x0, x1, y0, y1], origin='lower')
# ax[0].axis('off')
ax[0].set_xticks([])  # remove x ticks

ax[1].plot(np.linspace(x0, x1, N), values)
# move all ticks of the lower plot inward, set ticks at the 4 directions
ax[1].tick_params(axis='both', which='both', direction='in', left=True, right=True, top=True, bottom=True)
ax[1].xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(1))  # major ticks at whole hours
ax[1].xaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(1 / 6))  # minor ticks every 10 minutes

# optionally set ticklabels at the top of the bottom subplot
# secax = ax[1].secondary_xaxis('top')
# secax.tick_params(axis='x', direction='in', pad=-20) # negative padding to also move labels inside
# secax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(1))  # major ticks at whole hours

plt.show()
```

[image: demo plot]

Comment: As an alternative, `plt.pcolormesh` can here be used more conveniently.

Comment: Wow, thank you. How would I add a complete box of axes though?

Comment: @JohanC Yes, I believe so, thanks. I still might run into some issues incorporating a color bar, can I ping you in a question if this happens?

Comment: Just add a comment to this answer if an additional problem would pop up. About the colorbar, it would be useful knowing the exact range of the values, whether or not a lognorm is needed and whether or not my simulated image is sufficient realistic.  For the location of a colorbar, the easiest would be to create an extra subplot.